# WPF MVVM Binding nested property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I'm creating an application where users can edit master data of a child, and I'm trying to create a seamless experience for the user by saving the changes they've made to the child for them.

I have a model called Child.

```
class Child
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

I have a view (ChildMasterDataView) that display's the FirstName and Surname in textboxes that are editable.

```
<!--First name-->
<Label Content="First name:" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Child.FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

<!--Surname-->
<Label Content="Surname:" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Child.Surname, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

I have a class which handles the implementation of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

```
public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChangedEvent(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

I have a ViewModel which is supposed to save the changes made to the Firstname and Surname, when the respective property is changed. The problem is that the Firstname and Surname are nested properties of the Child class, and aren't firing the PropertyChanged event...

```
class ChildMasterDataViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private Database db; // Database context

    public ChildViewModel()
    {
        db = new Database();
        Child = db.Children.ToList().Where(e => e.PlbNr == 1).FirstOrDefault(); // Won't be null because child has been chosen earlier

        PropertyChanged += ChildPropertyChanged;
    }

    private Child child;
    public Child Child
    {
        get { return child; }
        set { child = value; RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Child"); }
    }

    private void ChildPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I can accomplish what I want by making the following changes to the ViewModel (and ofc changing the view binding):

```
class ChildMasterDataViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private Database db; // Database context
    private Child child;

    public ChildViewModel()
    {
        db = new Database();
        child = db.Children.ToList().Where(e => e.PlbNr == 1).FirstOrDefault(); // Won't be null because child has been chosen earlier

        PropertyChanged += ChildPropertyChanged;
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return child.FirstName; }
        set { child.FirstName= value; RaisePropertyChangedEvent("FirstName"); }
    }

    public string Surname
    {
        get { return child.Surname; }
        set { child.Surname= value; RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Surname"); }
    }

    private void ChildPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

This can't be right though, there must be a better way?

I have tried implementing ObservableObject in the Child class and then in the ViewModel subscribing the PropertyChanged event of the Child class to the ViewModel's ChildPropertyChanged method. This did not work.

Comment: There is only 3 ways to do that you want. 
1) Wrap model - you already made it, thought INotifiPropertyChanged would be more easy, imho.
2) You will add INotifyPropertyChanged directly to your model.
3) You will create a stadalone class that implement INotifypropertyChanged or derived from ObservableObject. And this class have to handle your model as **input** and handle it on it's own to initialize it's properties, that you will bind. You will need to make back transformation as well.

Comment: If you're binding to it, it should probably implement INotifyPropertyChanged.  And IDataErrorInfo, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I see there being no reason not to place a simple `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation into your Child model - after all it has properties that are changing. Now you can bind to them directly.

By the same token, why is saving state part of your ViewModel? I would move that into the model or into a separate persistence manager. The VM is supposed to model aspects of the View that are independent of the Model.

Comment: Could you show how you would bind to them? Because I've tried and I could not get it to work. How would I save the data via my model?

Comment: There is no special binding, your XAML is perfectly fine. You just need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on the Child class.

Comment: Although, word of caution, you currently have every keystroke triggering a database update...

Comment: I have implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged interface in my model once again, but this time I used a DataTemplate as well, and with the DataTemplate it works. Without the DataTemplate it won't work. I have a new issue though, my comboboxes that have a different ItemSource don't work anymore as I think they are being overridden or canceled out by the ContentControl & DataTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

When dependency property is starting to use binding, it try convert binding instance to INotifyPropertyChanged, and after by using "weak event" subscribe to event. So dependecy property know nothing about inner property and etc, it just try convert to INotifyPropertyChanged and suscribe to event. Next, when event wil be rise, dependency peroperty, using reflection, will be get new value (it's way to improve it, you can write your own kind of dependency property, which will be use Expression, for getting value from property)